# How can I pass recordtype to a custom Record

Tags: suitescript2.0

I have a custom record for a deployment script that has a specific field -
Type: list/record
Receives it's information from a Record Type List.

When I use getValue in that field, I get values like -215, - 235, etc. If I pass that field in order to set a new record, I get:
"You have entered an Invalid Field Value **parameter_passed** for the following field: recordtype"

I have tried **parameter_passed** with different values: -215 (direct value from getValue), "Accounting Context", "Accounting_Context", "ACCOUNTING_CONTEXT", "ACCOUNTINGCONTEXT"

I think it's a dictionary (or enum like structure) but can't find information. What kind of data should I pass to get my script working properly?

Code used:

```
    // get record from custom field
const deployment = newRecord.getValue({
    
            const deployment = newRecord.getText ({
    
              fieldId: 'custrecord_record_type'

// set value (not working)
deploymentRecord.setValue({

      fieldId: 'recordtype',

      value: deployment

    });
```

Deployment record is a record of  type: 'scriptdeployment',
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please, give the code, especially where you 'pass that field in order to set a new record'. I'm pretty sure the error is about a different thing

Comment: Hi,  added the code I'm using.

Comment: The field `recordtype` AFAIK cannot be 'set'. It's defined by NS, when the record is created and cannot be changed by simply setting its value. Don't know what's the whole idea of your script, but this can't be done `.setValue({fieldId: 'recordtype'`

Comment: How it does even work? I'm sure this exact code example doesn't work because it has syntax errors